# Update my php 5.3 to 5.4 issue

Tags: php, upgrade

I am new with servers, and I have tried updating my php  using yum, but I get the following error. I have tried almost everything but I can't figure it out.Please help me fix it.

Juan.

```
[root@myserver]# yum install php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, replace
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * epel: dl.fedoraproject.org
 * extras: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
 * remi: mirrors.mediatemple.net
 * updates: p3plmirror01.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
The program yum-complete-transaction is found in the yum-utils package.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.4.25-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.25-1.el6.remi for package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.25-1.el6.remi for package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit) for package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.4.25-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit) for package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.25-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) for package: php-cli-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) for package: php-cli-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit) for package: php-cli-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.25-1.el6.remi will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-5.4.25-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Why are you using an external repo if you don't know what you are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is happening because the version of OpenSSL installed on your box is < 1.0.1, most likely 1.0.0.

You should be careful with using external repositories if you are not familiar with resolving dependency problems, such as this one.

Locate an appropriate RPM for your operating system that contains the missing files ( OpenSSL 1.0.1+ ) and that will resolve your dependency errors.